# Django Crispy Forms with MaterializeCSS

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

I am trying to write a helper to render MaterializeCSS forms with Django-crispy-forms. So far I couldn't find how to implement the  tags properly or the form in general, to make them slide up in animation when active (A material thing, can be observed here: [MaterializeCSS FormFields](https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html)).

My code looks like this:

```
class SignUpForm(CustomUserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'password1', 'password2',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Div(
                    Field('email', css_class='validate'),
                    css_class='input-field col s12'
                ),
                css_class='row'
            ),
            Div(
                Div(
                    Field('password1', css_class='validate'),
                    css_class='input-field col s12'
                ),
                css_class='row'
            ),
            Div(
                Div(
                    Field('password2', css_class='validate'),
                    css_class='input-field col s12'
                ),
                css_class='row'
            ),
        )
```

I am afraid I am making this overly complicated. Is there any better way to accomplish such html structure for my form with django-crispy-forms? Or would you suggest a different approach all-together, like not using crispy forms?

Here is the HTML I am trying to replicate form my form:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I switched to use 'django-widget-tweaks' and structured my form template with html manually instead. But still a solution with crispy forms would be better i think.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the form.<<field_name>> inside Materializecss divs and you will get your desired output.

```
<div class="row queryForm">
    <form class="col s12" id="p-form" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          {{form.name}}
          <label for="last_name">Your Name</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          {{form.email}}
          <label for="email">Email</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          {{form.phone}}
          <label for="icon_telephone">Phone Number</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          {{form.query}}
          <label for="textarea">Query</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

An example of my form is here with the output.

[image]